# What do you call the plastic/rubber protector on electrical connectors like headphone jacks?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

In the image below, between the connector and the cable is a bit of stiff plastic that covers and protects the joint. The entire covering, from where the metal ends (visually) to where uniform cable begins (visually). Is there a (preferably non-technical) term for this?

[image: turtles]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different functions or features coincident with the concept you wish to terminologically identify

- stud insulation
- termination
- sleeving aka boot
- strain relief
- permanently set, aka premolded (and therefore not a boot)

Each of these functions can be had independent of the other. For example, you can have a strain relief elbow which is not a terminal. You could also have a strain relief elbow which is also a termination. There frequently are straight strain relief sleeves about a foot away from the terminal end of USB cables. I guess that is where cables usually get tangled and mangled up.

You could have a termination that is not qualified for strain relief. In which case, you should not contractually tell your client that it is a strain-relieved terminal end.

In many cases, terminal ends are manually crimped as the "cable guy" requires the flexibility of non-predetermined cable lengths before cutting the cable and crimping on the termination sleeve. In such case, the wire or cable termination is usually commercially advertised as terminal sleeves. If strain relief is required, then strain-relieved terminal sleeves/boots. Where the terminal sleeve is appended with the stud appropriate to the occasion.

- termination stud insulation
- termination stud insulation sleeve
- termination stud insulation sleeve with strain relief
- premolded termination stud insulation with strain relief
- premolded insulated termination elbow stud with angular strain relief

**Reinvent the wheel**

If you might seek to reinvent a term for it especially if you are involved in an entrepreneurial venture to produce such structures, you could use the term `varix`. Plural `varices`, from which is derived the term for medical conditions of varicose veins or arteries. Variac might be a good brand name.

[Varix](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=varix) = a swollen section because it is identifiably different (vary) from the rest.

- premolded termination varix/varices.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since it has a few more alternatives. I think "strain relief sleeve" will describe it well to a laymen who would be unfamiliar with "termination stud" "boot". Also, I wasn't planning on it, but now I need to come up with a product so I can use "Varix" :D

Comment: Not that I care that much, but if you're asking for a appropriate term exists, wouldn't you want evidence that the term is actually used for that purpose in practice? I thought I knew something about this subject, and those few more alternatives that you like don't conform with my experience.

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in a functional description, it's called **strain relief** or a **strain reliever**.

It's purpose is to remove the strain from the wires that are inside and distribute it over the mechanical structure of the connector.

Google "[connector strain relief](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+strain+relief&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=4gogUrytHrKMigKY_oCYBA&ved=0CFkQsAQ&biw=1440&bih=766)" for pictures.

It's also called a **boot**.

Google "[connector boot](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+boot&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=LAwgUrf1M6jGiwLQwoDgCw&ved=0CDAQsAQ&biw=1440&bih=766)" for pictures under this name.

Boot is [defined as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boot) a protective covering, especially a sheath to enclose the base of a floor-mounted gear shift lever in a car or truck

Answer (score 0):

The name of the plastic connector with an interior copper spring you twist over the end of bare electrical wire end(s) to secure them and prevent short circuits is a marrette. They come in various colours and sizes to fit one or more different gauge wires. One company that makes them is Thomas Betts

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. Your answer may well be correct, but we have no way of telling. Rather than just giving us the name of a company that makes them, you should link to a page on their website corroborating your answer. (That's how this list operates.)

Comment: No, a marette is something completely different.

Comment: *wire nuts* don't have anything to do with headphones or their connectors.